# Git modified files in master and branches

Tags: git, branch, difference

I've started two weeks ago using Git. 
For now I do only commit and push. 
I did a mistake and I've created a branch. 
Now I have a file, say "main.js" that has important changes in both branches.

In general : I have master that is production, then the dev branch, and a hot fix branch. 
I've changed main.js in dev,  then I must change it in hot fix to solve a bug, and I merge hot fix in master. 
Now master and dev has disalligned main.js.
How to maintain a situation like that?

Edit :
Maybe im using git completly wrong ...
I do some practical examples :

master - main.js - created 01/01/2017

```
function main() { 
    start(); 
}
```

dev - main.js - modified 07/01/2017

```
function main() { 
    new_stuff_1();
    start(new_param);
    new_stuff_2();  
}
```

hotfix - main.js - modified 10/01/2017

```
function main() { 
    hotfix();
    start();
}
```

After all merges i hope to have :

```
function main() { 
        hotfix();
        new_stuff_1();
        start(new_param);
        new_stuff_2();  
    }
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but it isn't clear what your exact problem is.  Files become "disalligned" between branches all the time in Git, this is a normal thing.

Comment: There isn't much of a question here.  Just merge the branches back to their sources in the reverse order, making sure that the changes you want are being preserved, and you should be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in `hotfix` branch, update the `main.js` file and commit those changes.
Then `checkout` to `dev` branch.

`git checkout dev`

Merge your changes from hotfix into dev.

`git merge hotfix`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, now that you have made your fix and merged it to master, you also have to merge your hotfix in the dev branch. this way you'll get to merge both your modification you've made on your main.js

here is a good document on how working with branches on git: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/.